# how to get a long horizontal line in tables

Tags: tabu

i have a table of 14 columns, i Drew it with `tabu` and now the horizontal line stops shortly.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,french,12pt,oneside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[french]{babel} %langue francaise
\usepackage{multirow,array}
%\usepackage{longtable}%pour la liste des symbole en format tableau
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{float}
    \begin{document}
       \begin{table}[H]
    \footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
    \begin{tabu}{l*{14}{c}}
    \toprule
    Supports& \multicolumn{14}{c}{Espèces chimiques (\si{\percent})}\\
    \midrule
    &\ch{MgO}&\ch{Al2O3}&\ch{SiO2}&\ch{P2O5}&\ch{SO3}&\ch{Cl}&\ch{K2O}&\ch{CaO}&\ch{TiO2}&\ch{Fe2O3}&\ch{ZnO}&\ch{MnO}&\ch{Ba}\\
    C.A.S&5,7&3,5&17,9&5,6&5,61&19,0&19,4&15,4&0,5&4,7&0,9&0,04&0,0\\
    C.A.C&3,6&4,8&11,2&2,8&1,2&2,2&22,2&23,1&1,27&0,8&0,9&0,8&0,1\\
    \bottomrule
    \addlinespace
    \multicolumn{15}{l}{C.A.S: Charbon Actif Synthétique}\\
    \multicolumn{15}{l}{C.A.C: Charbon Actif Commercial}
    \end{tabu}
    \end{table}
    ~\\
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: your example produces `! Undefined control sequence. \si`  and other errors apparently unrelated to your question?

Comment: Probably your table is wider than `\textwidth`, and `\toprule` and the like stop at the right margin. You should check with the `showframe` package.

Comment: I added 'siunitx' package @DavidCarlisle

Comment: Is it a solution or i missed another package?

Comment: `\ch` is still undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `\cline{1-14}`. It works.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,french,12pt,oneside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[french]{babel} %langue francaise
\usepackage{multirow,array}
%\usepackage{longtable}%pour la liste des symbole en format tableau
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{float}
\newcommand{\ch}{}
    \begin{document}
       \begin{table}[H]
    \footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
    \begin{tabu}{l*{14}{c}}
    \cline{1-14}
    Supports& \multicolumn{13}{c}{Espèces chimiques (\si{\percent})}\\
    \cline{1-14}
    &\ch{MgO}&\ch{Al2O3}&\ch{SiO2}&\ch{P2O5}&\ch{SO3}&\ch{Cl}&\ch{K2O}&\ch{CaO}&\ch{TiO2}&\ch{Fe2O3}&\ch{ZnO}&\ch{MnO}&\ch{Ba}\\
    C.A.S&5,7&3,5&17,9&5,6&5,61&19,0&19,4&15,4&0,5&4,7&0,9&0,04&0,0\\
    C.A.C&3,6&4,8&11,2&2,8&1,2&2,2&22,2&23,1&1,27&0,8&0,9&0,8&0,1\\
    \cline{1-14}
    \addlinespace
    \multicolumn{15}{l}{C.A.S: Charbon Actif Synthétique}\\
    \multicolumn{15}{l}{C.A.C: Charbon Actif Commercial}
    \end{tabu}
    \end{table}
    ~\\
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, But why the Especes chimique is not centered? I typed {c}

Comment: Changing it to \multicolumn{13}{c}{Espèces chimiques (\si{\percent})} does it because there are totally 14 columns.

Comment: Oh god, you are right.

Comment: Edited my answer :)

Comment: @AmbikaVanchinathan You can even use the usual `toprule` and others. That was just a silly mistake.

Comment: @Johannes_B No, it is not working with top and bottom rule :(

Comment: @AmbikaVanchinathan Right, `tabu` annoys once more. Works with regular `tabular`, see below.

Comment: @Hamza.w You can change the thickness of the rule with cline as\cline{2pt}{1-14} etc.

Comment: @Johannes_B that was my first guess but switching to tabular shows the same.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The first thing i did was getting rid of the additional information on the bottom. Is that the causing thing? Let me check. EDIT: Yes, they are the culprit.

Comment: using cline though loses the benefits booktabs gives to more formal spacing to rules, cline has even less space than \hline and a lit less than abottomrule.

Answer (score 4):

It is easier to see what's wrong of you make a *minimal* example.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}


\noindent X\dotfill X

\begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
\toprule
xxxx&yyyy&zzzzz\\
1&2&3\\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{5}{l}{C.A.C}
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{*{3}{c}}
\toprule
xxxx&yyyy&zzzzz\\
1&2&3\\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{3}{l}{C.A.C}
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

As seen here `booktabs` has this effect if you specify too many columns.
You have 14 not 15 columns. Also it helps if you test the example `\ch` is not defined in the question as posted.

A corrected table is

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,french,12pt,oneside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[french]{babel} %langue francaise
\usepackage{multirow,array}
%\usepackage{longtable}%pour la liste des symbole en format tableau
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\def\ch{}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{float}
    \begin{document}
       \begin{table}[H]
    \footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
    \begin{tabu}{l*{13}{c}}
    \toprule
    Supports& \multicolumn{13}{c}{Espèces chimiques (\si{\percent})}\\
    \midrule
    &\ch{MgO}&\ch{Al2O3}&\ch{SiO2}&\ch{P2O5}&\ch{SO3}&\ch{Cl}&\ch{K2O}&\ch{CaO}&\ch{TiO2}&\ch{Fe2O3}&\ch{ZnO}&\ch{MnO}&\ch{Ba}\\
    C.A.S&5,7&3,5&17,9&5,6&5,61&19,0&19,4&15,4&0,5&4,7&0,9&0,04&0,0\\
    C.A.C&3,6&4,8&11,2&2,8&1,2&2,2&22,2&23,1&1,27&0,8&0,9&0,8&0,1\\
    \bottomrule
    \addlinespace
    \multicolumn{14}{l}{C.A.S: Charbon Actif Synthétique}\\
    \multicolumn{14}{l}{C.A.C: Charbon Actif Commercial}
    \end{tabu}
    \end{table}
%NO!!    ~\\
    \end{document}
```

Comment: *You have 14 not 14 columns.* Should i change the wording concerning the bug in my answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B yes probably remove the bit about tabu in `No bug, just faulty input. Avoiding tabu alltogether works perfectly fine` and delete `Till the bug gets fixed you can use a manual workaround.`

Comment: @Johannes_B thanks fixed to say 14 not 15.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with `tabular` alone, i don't see an advantage of using `tabu` here.

[image: hamzaTabularLine]

```
\documentclass[french]{memoir}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
    \begin{tabular}{l*{14}{c}}
        \toprule
        Supports& \multicolumn{13}{c}{Espèces chimiques (\si{\percent})}\\
        \midrule
        &\ch{MgO}&\ch{Al2O3}&\ch{SiO2}&\ch{P2O5}&\ch{SO3}&\ch{Cl}&\ch{K2O}&\ch{CaO}&\ch{TiO2}&\ch{Fe2O3}&\ch{ZnO}&\ch{MnO}&\ch{Ba}\\
        C.A.S&5,7&3,5&17,9&5,6&5,61&19,0&19,4&15,4&0,5&4,7&0,9&0,04&0,0\\
        C.A.C&3,6&4,8&11,2&2,8&1,2&2,2&22,2&23,1&1,27&0,8&0,9&0,8&0,1\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}\smallbreak
        {C.A.S: Charbon Actif Synthétique}\par
        {C.A.C: Charbon Actif Commercial}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

Even with an incorrect amount of columns, you can use a `p`-column to trick to use the right (estimated) width.

But i would even transform the whole table.

[image: hamzaTabularLineOld]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \footnotesize\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.5pt}
    \begin{tabular}{l*{14}{c}}
        \toprule
        Supports& \multicolumn{14}{>{\centering}p{.86\linewidth}}{Espèces chimiques (\si{\percent})}\\
        \midrule
        &\ch{MgO}&\ch{Al2O3}&\ch{SiO2}&\ch{P2O5}&\ch{SO3}&\ch{Cl}&\ch{K2O}&\ch{CaO}&\ch{TiO2}&\ch{Fe2O3}&\ch{ZnO}&\ch{MnO}&\ch{Ba}\\
        C.A.S&5,7&3,5&17,9&5,6&5,61&19,0&19,4&15,4&0,5&4,7&0,9&0,04&0,0\\
        C.A.C&3,6&4,8&11,2&2,8&1,2&2,2&22,2&23,1&1,27&0,8&0,9&0,8&0,1\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}\smallbreak
        {C.A.S: Charbon Actif Synthétique}\par
        {C.A.C: Charbon Actif Commercial}
\end{table}

\begin{tabular}{cSS}
    \toprule
    {Espèces chimiques (\si{\percent})} & {CAS} & {CAC} \\
    \midrule
    \ch{MgO} & 5.7 & 3.6 \\
    \ch{Al2O3} & 3.5 & 4.8 \\
    \ch{TiO2} & 0.5 & 1.27 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}



%~\\ % BAD
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Mico Oh, you are right, i'll fix asap. Thanks. Did not even notice that.

Comment: @Mico Wow, took me eleven minutes to adjust that.

Comment: I deleted my comment that it was a bug, really it's incorrect input (although booktabs behaviour on that input isn't really expected:-) see my answer